# MiniMagick Error: How to generate OG image with MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm working on a Rails application. It generates OG image drawn to text a user inputs. For example, you input "Hello world", save it, and then an application generates an OG image written to "Hello world".

But it occurs to this error:
[image]

*apps/controllers/reviews_controller.rb*

```
include SetupOgbImage

def create
  @review = current_user.active_reviews.create(create_params)
  @review.image = build(@review.content)
  if @review.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfully added a review!"
    redirect_to review_path(id: @review.id)
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Failed to add a review."
    redirect_to user_path(id: @review.reviewed_id)
  end
end
```

*apps/controllers/concerns/setup_ogb_image.rb*

```
module SetupOgbImage
    def build(text)
        text = prepare_text(text)
        img = MiniMagick::Image.open(Settings.ogb.base_image_path)
        img.combine_options do |config|
        config.font Settings.ogb.font_path
        config.fill Settings.ogb.color
        config.gravity Settings.ogb.gravity
        config.pointsize Settings.ogb.font_size
        config.draw "text #{Settings.ogb.text_position} #{text}"
        end
        img
    end

    def prepare_text(text)
        text.scan(/.{1,#{Settings.ogb.indention_count}}/)[0...Settings.ogb.row_limit].join("\n")
    end
end
```

*settings.yml*

```
ogb:
  base_image_path: ./app/assets/images/ogb_bg_image.png
  gravity: center
  text_position: "0,30"
  font_path: ./app/assets/fonts/Hind-Medium.ttf
  font_size: 24
  color: "#fff"
  indention_count: 60
  row_limit: 10
format:
  uuid: !ruby/regexp /\A[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}\z/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the text into quotes, otherwise, the shell that is, in turn, executing the command, treats “Hello” and “world!” as two different arguments in call to `mogrify`:

```
#                                               ⇓       ⇓
config.draw "text #{Settings.ogb.text_position} '#{text}'"
```